# Unity activate something only first collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My aim is activate an event inside the OnTriggerEnter function only for once.

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("Player");
    Player player = obj.GetComponent<Player>();
    bool isCollide = false;
    
    if (coll.GetComponent<Collider>().CompareTag("Player"))
    {

        if (isCollide == false)
        {
            isCollide = true;
            Instantiate(instantiatedObj, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, 3, this.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else
            isCollide = false;
        
        }
    }
```

However, when I press play, it instantiates the instantiatedObj in every collision. I just want to make this happen only first collision.

Comment: Should the event trigger again if the two objects stop colliding and start colliding again?

Comment: No. the event shoud only trigger in first collision. When they collide again, the event should not be activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are resetting your `IsCollide` to false each time you enter the `OnTriggerEnter` for the second time.

To really ensure that you only Instantiate it on the first Collision, you would need to remove that reset.

**Example:**

```cs
// Check if isCollide is set to false
if (!isCollide) {
    // If it is then set it to true, so it won't be called again
    isCollide = true;
    // and execute any code we don't want to be called again
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isCollide` is being set to false for every collision because `OnTriggerEnter` is called for every collision.

Move `isCollide` to outside of method, make it class property so it will be kept.

```
public bool isCollide {get;set;}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){
   ...
}
```